# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o114.json. : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, pyspark, heap-memory, space

I'm trying to fix it with this code but it's not working for me .
i'm reading just a json file with 2.7 MB

```
conf = SparkConf().set("spark.cores.max", "16g") \
   .set("spark.driver.memory", "16g") \
   .set("spark.executor.memory", "16g") \
   .set("spark.executor.memory_overhead", "16g") \
   .set("spark.driver.maxResultsSize", "0")

spark = SparkSession.builder\
      .master("local[1]")\
      .appName("name")\
      .config(conf=conf)\
      .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error)

Comment: this link is helpful is someone has the same problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48726208/how-do-i-read-a-large-json-array-file-in-pyspark)